# Mapdispatchtoprops not giving function to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ShelfModal } from "./shelf-modal";
import { openShelfModal } from "../../../redux/actions/shelf-modal";

export class ShelfTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {
    const { openModal } = this.props;


    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={openModal}>Open Shelf</button>

        <ShelfModal />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
         openModal: () => dispatch(openShelfModal())
       });

export const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ShelfTest);
```

Above is code to a modal that I am using. I am trying to get the `openModal` function in `mapDispatchToProps` inside the `render` as `props` but it's not showing up inside `props`. The actions are imported from correct path. What is wrong here?

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` as you are exporting them along with the `ShelfTest` via `connect`.

I restructured your `mapDispatchToProps` as well for good measure.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { ShelfModal } from "./shelf-modal";
import { openShelfModal } from "../../../redux/actions/shelf-modal";

class ShelfTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {
    const { openModal } = this.props;


    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={openModal}>Open Shelf</button>

        <ShelfModal />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
         openModal(){
            dispatch(openShelfModal())
         }
      }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ShelfTest);
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can try including `openShelfModal` in your connect statement by itself. Rather than declaring `mapDispatchToProps`, you can structure your export with connect like so.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {openShelfModal}) (ShelfTest);
```

As long as your middleware/routing is properly set up this should work.

You also don't need `export class ShelfTest extends Component {` at the top if you're exporting it at the bottom with `connect`.

Comment: thanks, but i am still stuck at the original issue, where openModal function from dispatchtoprops is still not available as a prop inside render

Comment: If you put a `debugger` underneath `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {` what does `openShelfModal` look like?

Comment: I updated the answer, try temporarily mapping `openShelfModal` that way. Otherwise it might be something wrong with your actions or your middleware/routing.

Comment: i checked this, its still not working, how do i debug the middleware/routing. Any pointers ?

Comment: I also noticed that you don't need `export class ShelfTest extends Component {` at the top if you're exporting it at the bottom with `connect`.  As for pointers how is your  middleware set up? Are you using redux-sagas? If `openShelfModal` is zero in your `mapDispatchToProps` then something might be wrong with the import of that function or the export. If you add your actions that might be helpful.

Comment: exporting mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProp shouldn't be issue. you can have as many named export as you want.

Comment: did you logged the props ? what is the output and check your import whether you have did the named import or default import since,you have exported in both ways.

Comment: @eramit2010 it's not good practice to include unnecessary exports in a react component.

Answer (score 0):

````
Here is the sample working code - 
try to import * actions and use bindactioncreators.

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import setDropdownFormat from '../../../Utils/setVesselFormat';
import './Header.css';
//Redux and state imports
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
//Actions
import * as vesselListActions from '../../../redux/actions/vesselListActions';

const Header = props => {
  const [vesselList, setVesselList] = useState();
  const [isVesselApiLoaded, setIsVesselApiLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.SHIP_API_BASE_URL}/crew/vessels`)
      .then(
        response => setVesselList(setDropdownFormat(response.data, 'id', 'name', 'imo')),
        setIsVesselApiLoaded(true),
      );
    props.setVesselList({ ...vesselList });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="layout-header">
      <div className="vessel-dropdown-container">
        {isVesselApiLoaded && vesselList && <VesselDropdown options={vesselList} />}
      </div>
      <div className="avatar-container">
        <Avatar size={AvatarSizes.Small} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Header.propTypes = {
  dataTestId: PropTypes.string,
};

Header.defaultProps = {
  dataTestId: 'header',
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    vessels: state.vesselList,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ ...vesselListActions }, dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);```
````

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.